# Prolog predicate that returns true if # is the first element of a List

Tags: prolog

I want to write a predicate that receives a list and is true if the first element of a list is '#', but I dont want it to unify in case it isn't.

for example

```
? - List=[#, _ , _ ,_]

? - mypredicate(List)
true.

? - List=[_,#, _ , _ , _]

? - mypredicate(List)
False.
```

What I've written is:

```
mypredicate([L]) :-
    nth0(0, L, #).
```

The problem is that in case the first element is not a '#' then it changes the list L by unifying # to the 1st element. I don't want it to unify, I just want it to check if it's true or false.

I also need a different predicate to verify if '#' is the last element of a list, I wrote:

```
mypredicate2(L) :-
    last(L, #).
```

The problem is the same on both predicates, it changes the element of the original list to # if it's not already a #. I don't want it to unify.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of [**`==/2`** [swi-doc]](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=(%3D%3D)/2) to check if:

> `True` **if `Term1` is equivalent to `Term2`**. A variable is only identical to a sharing variable.

So here you can write a predicate that looks like:

```
mypredicate([X|_]) :-
    X == # .
```

I leave the predicate that checks if the last item is a `#` as an exercise.